# Beautiful Soup not able to handle a large file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a huge XML file (1.2 G) containing info about millions of MusicAlbums each having a simple format as following

```
    <MusicAlbum>
      <MusicType>P</MusicType>
      <Title>22 Exitos de Oro [Brentwood]</Title>
      <Performer>Chayito Valdéz</Performer>
    </MusicAlbum>
...
    <MusicAlbum>
      <MusicType>A</MusicType>
      <Title>Bye Bye</Title>
      <Performer>Emma Aster</Performer>
    </MusicAlbum>
```

I can read and load the file just fine in Python but when I pass it to Beautifulsoup

```
html = FID.read()
print "Converting to Soup"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print "Conversion Completed"
```

I get this

```
Converting to Soup
Killed
```

apparently Killed is something that Beautifulsoup prints.
One solution is to break down html, into blocks each containing the info"MusicAlbum" and "/MusicAlbum" blocks and then pass them to Beautifulsoup but just wanted to make sure if there is an easier solution.

Comment: BeautifulSoup raises MemoryError if it runs out of memory. So this should be because of something else right?

Comment: Well there are so many MusicAlbum objects , so it is a memory problem what do you mean by something else?

Comment: I would write a quick piece of python that split this huge piece of HTML into individual records. I assume that you really want this imported into a database to work on a portion of the data at a time.

Comment: Why not use an xml parser instead of beautifulsoup?

Comment: Actually, since I've worked with huge (200Mb) xml files in python before, I'd say it is not realistic with any real xml parser (to the best of my knowledge) if you don't have a supercomputer. I solved my case with writing my slimmed xml-parser using regular expressions for the information I needed. Still it takes about 10 - 15 min when I slimmed my file down to 50 Mb

Comment: If you are interested I could of course post snipplets from my regex xml sequential parser (but it builds no xpaths or anything, just reads data into lists and converts it into numpy arrays after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works for you, it won't be fast but shouldn't use more memory than you need:

```
# encoding:utf-8
import re

data = """    <MusicAlbum>
      <MusicType>P</MusicType>
      <Title>22 Exitos de Oro [Brentwood]</Title>
      <Performer>Chayito Valdéz</Performer>
    </MusicAlbum>
...
    <MusicAlbum>
      <MusicType>A</MusicType>
      <Title>Bye Bye</Title>
      <Performer>Emma Aster</Performer>
    </MusicAlbum>"""

MA = re.compile(r'<MusicAlbum>(.*?)</MusicAlbum>', re.DOTALL)
TY = re.compile(r'<MusicType>(.*)</MusicType>')
TI = re.compile(r'<Title>(.*)</Title>')
P = re.compile(r'<Performer>(.*)</Performer>')

albums = []
for album in re.findall(MA, data):
    albums.append({
        'type': re.search(TY, album).group(),
        'title': re.search(TI, album).group(),
        'performer': re.search(P, album).group()})


print albums
```

Comment: If any of the TY, TI or P can span over more than one line add the ´re.DOTALL´ to it...